# C# getting array with a string name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So here's a hypothetical. From someone fairly new to the whole C# and Unity thing:
Suppose for a moment that I have a series of string[] arrays. All of which have similar naming convention. For example:

```
public string[] UndeadEntities =
{
    // stuff
};

public string[] DemonEntities =
{
    // stuff
};
```

Now suppose I want to call one of them at random, I have another list that contains the names of all of those arrays and I return it at random. 
My problem is that I grab the name from the array and it's a string, not something I can use. So my question is this: 
is there any way for me to use this string and use it to call the above mentioned arrays.

Something like this is what I'm up to but unsure where to go from here and I really would like to avoid making a massive series of If Else statements just for that.

```
public string[] EnemiesType = { // list of all the other arrays }
public string enemiesTypeGeneratedArrayName = "";

public void GenerateEncounterGroup()
{
    enemiesTypeGeneratedArrayName = EnemiesType[Random.Range(0, 12)];
}
```

Can I nest arrays inside of other arrays? Is there another alternative?
I'm not sure if it is possible at all but if it is, I'll take any pointers as to where to go from there. Thanks.

Comment: `this.GetType().GetField(enemiesTypeGeneratedArrayName).GetValue(this)`

Comment: "Can I nest arrays inside of other arrays?" - this would be super simple to check, or search online for that matter. But yes... that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions to your specific problem, an easy one is using Dictionaries:

A Dictionary is a data structure wher you have a key (usually a string) and a value (whatever type you may want to store).

What you can do is at start, initialized a Dictionary were each key is your enemy type, and the value it store is your array, something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> enemyArrays= new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
.
void Start()
{
   enemyArrays["typeA"] = myArrayA;
   enemyArrays["typeB"] = myArrayB;
}
```

Then when you need to get that array, just:

```
enemiesTypeGeneratedArrayName = EnemiesType[Random.Range(0, 12)];
string[] myRandomArray =enemyArrays[enemiesTypeGeneratedArrayName];
string randomEnemy = myRandomArray[index];
```

Here you can read more about [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) class if you want.

There are other ways to do it, but I think this one is pretty easy to implement in the code you already made, and Dicionaries are cool haha.

I hope is clear:)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll check out how to set up Dictionaries, that's mighty helpful